# How to include Javascript & jQuery into HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I am doing a sample application. In my application I am trying to insert javascript into the html. But I am not getting the desired result.

I had downloaded a tab form and [**this link**](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2009/09/stylish-navigation-menu-jquery/#) provides a demo what it actually looks like

My jsp file

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"
prefix="form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <style>
        form
        {
            width: 400px;
        }
        label
        {
            float: left;
            width: 150px;
        }
        input[type=text]
        {
            float: left;
            width: 250px;
        }
        .clear
        {
            clear: both;
            height: 0;
            line-height: 0;
        }
        .floatright
        {
            float: right;
        }
    </style>
    <style type="text/css">
     <%@include file="tab/demo.css" %> 
     </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tab/jquery-2.0.3.js" ></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="tab/script.js" ></script>  
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.1.js"></script>
         <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        Home</p>
    <div id="tabs">
       <ul id="navigationMenu">
  <li> <a href ="#tab-1" class="selectedMenu">Home</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#tab-2 " class="normalMenu">Teams</a></li> 
  <li> <a href="#tab-3 " class="normalMenu">Events</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-4" class="normalMenu">The team</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tab-5" class="normalMenu">About us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-6" class="normalMenu">Contact us</a></li>
  </ul>       
        <div id="tab-1">
            <h1>
                new entry1</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="tab-2">
            <h1>
                new entry2</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="tab-3">
            <h1>
                new entry3</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I had placed the files inside `web-inf/views/tab/` and the

> tab

folder contains

> demo.css, script.js, jquery-2.0.3.js.

the ing files are contained in

> views/img

The **script.js** file

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

$('#navigationMenu li .normalMenu').each(function(){

    $(this).before($(this).clone().removeClass().addClass('hoverMenu'));

});


$('#navigationMenu li').hover(function(){

    $(this).find('.hoverMenu').stop().animate({marginTop:'0px'},200);

},

function(){

    $(this).find('.hoverMenu').stop().animate({marginTop:'-25px'},200);

});

    });
```

and the **demo.css**

```
/* Page styles */

   body,h1,h2,h3,p,td,quote,small,form,input,ul,li,ol,label{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
   }

  body{
margin-top:20px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color:#51555C;
height:100%;
font-size:12px;
   }

  /* Navigation menu styles */

    ul{
height:25px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
   }

 ul li{
border:1px solid #444444;
display:inline-block;
float:left;
height:25px;
list-style-type:none;
overflow:hidden;
    }

  ul li a, ul li a:hover, 
     ul li a:visited{
text-decoration:none;
      }

      .normalMenu, .normalMenu:visited,
    .hoverMenu, .hoverMenu:visited,
    .selectedMenu,.selectedMenu:visited {
outline:none;
padding:5px 10px;
display:block;
    }

   .hoverMenu,.hoverMenu:visited,
      .selectedMenu,.selectedMenu:visited {
margin-top:-25px;
background:url(img/grey_bg.gif) repeat-x #eeeeee;
color:#444444;
    }

     .selectedMenu,.selectedMenu:visited {
margin:0;
  }

  .normalMenu, .normalMenu:visited{
color:white;
background:url(img/dark_bg.gif) repeat-x #444444;
   }
```

i want to get the output like this http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2009/09/stylish-navigation-menu-jquery/#. what i am getting is same as the above tab,but the animation is not working andt when i select the second tab first one still showing highlited. On checking i found that the

> script.js

file is not reading. Even if we delete the

> script.js

file the result is same that is the tab will shows up but no animation and first tab is always highlited.

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain your exact problem? Make sure the path tab/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js is correct.

Comment: `But I am not getting the desired result.` What is the current result and what is the desired result?

Comment: @FrançoisWahl thanks for helping me,i have updated more on this problem

Comment: @Yasitha thanks for helping me,i have updated more details on this problem

Answer (score -1):

In the [jquery UI](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/) documentation you will see they call the script after the dom elements have been created.  Try moving the script tags to just befor the body close tags and see if that works

Comment: The script is wrapped in a DOM ready event handler. Moving the script won't fix any problems.